How do I recreate this holes pattern?
I been trying to recreate this pattern, but can not get my head around it. I recreated the upper pattern, but I couldn’t get it on the plane, and even if I did, I have no idea on how to add the other holes. Do I need more geometry?



it looks like the main pattern is something like that, so create a grid and select all these vertices:

Bevel with CtrlB and V:

Then subdivide and right click > LoopTools > Circle:

Delete the faces:


how about the small ones ? i want it to be as similar as possibile i dont want to just make holes ther, and with you method i would have to connect all the vertics right ?

You need to keep working on it afterwards
